# Analogue of orbit counting formula in $F[x]$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, algebraic-number-theory, finite-fields, function-fields

We know that if $G$ is a finite group acting on a finite set $\Omega$, then $$\sum_{g\in G}\chi(g)\equiv 0\pmod{|G|}$$ where $\chi$ is the permutation character. I wonder if is there an analogue of this formula in $F[x]$ where $F$ is a finite field. More clearly, given a finite group $G$, do we have a formula with a polynomial $f$ such that $$\sum_{g\in G}\chi(g)\equiv 0\pmod f$$ where $\chi$ is some sort of a polynomial valued function.

Comment: Any relation between $\Omega$ and $F$?

Comment: Well, if is there general formula, then not. But in the cases I work on, $G$ acts on itself and $G$ is a subset of $\overline{F}$.